# Protecting Node Server with Basic HTTP Auth

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs, basic-authentication

I'm running a Mean.js app on a server, but I want to run a test environment as well that is password protected. I tried doing it with [http-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-auth) set up like so

```
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ... 
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);
app.use(auth.connect(basic));
```

When I do this, there was no authentication done on the front end. As a sanity check I changed `var basic` to

```
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
}, function(username, password, callback) {
    console.log("Authenticating");
    callback(username === "username" && password === "password");
});
```

And nothing even printed to the console. So I'm thinking that this method of authentication is not working.

In the past I have used Apache PasswordBasicAuth to protect an application, which is very simple. Is there any way to do a comparable authentication in Node?

Comment: I can confirm that you used correct syntax for http-auth module, if custom authentication does not work too then you must have problem with require('./config/express')(db); line.